# Deploying asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an asp.net application which uses some web services(WCF) in the solution exporer ( Through add reference). I can see that end points are defined in Web.config

Now i do not want to touch the web config in the production and i have two questions.
1. What dll should i be putting on production - Released one or debug dll.
2. Whatever is taken as reference (WCF) in our asp.net applicaiton. I hope only defining end point is sufficent assuming that i havent changed anything in the WCF Service.

I will appreciate if someone can guide in this regard.

Thanks in Advance- New to .net :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to your questions, here are the answers

1) On production servers "Release" build (dlls) is the best bet because they are optimized for performance. you don't need to add the reference again, unless there is some code change (which changes the wsdl of service)

2) End points will not be changed, therefore just by copy new service dlls, you should be good to go. The types in config file remain the same as in WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your VSS for Configuration Manager,which one you are pointing it.It can be release or debug.
Whichever is choosen,you have deploy the corresponding one.WCF service,defining end point is fine.